# How best to duplicate an Android project?

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

I've built an Android project that I'd like to clone, rename and rebrand but I'm not sure how best to do this. I assume I could just make a copy of the project files and then go through the entire tree renaming the com.domain.project references etc, but surely there's a more 'proper' way of doing this?

The project was built in Android Studio and it's a Phonegap based app. Perhaps the only way would be to use Phonegap to create a new project and then replace the assets tree?

Comment: yes replace www folder in new project it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. copy the project.
2. Change the project name 
   3.change its package name using refactor.
3. change package name fom manifest file.
4. change app name aswell.
5. Remove all errors if any.
6. import new project into eclipse.

Comment: Thanks Sandiskp, this seems to be the closest answer although I'm not using Eclipse here.

I cloned the files to a new directory and imported that project into Android Studio which asked for the new project name. I then right clicked the src/com.domain.project file and used refactor-rename to rename the project, then right clicked the child file and did the same refactor to rename the package. Most of the other files seem to have picked up on these changes and the app runs just fine :-).

Answer (score 1):

> Project Name:

res -> values -> strings.xml -> app_name -> (change the name)

Package name:

Right click on the project -> Android tools -> Rename application package -> (change the name)