# How best to duplicate an phonegap project

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I've built an Phonegap project that I'd like to clone, rename and redisign but I'm not sure how best to do this. I assume I could just make a copy of the project files.
The project was built in Android Studio and xcode and it's a Phonegap based app. Perhaps the only way would be to use Phonegap to create a new project and then replace the assets tree?

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014339/how-best-to-duplicate-an-android-project

Comment: in xcode return error  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'ERROR: config.xml not found in the main bundle!'

Comment: I realise this is old but I just had the same issue after duplicating an Xcode (12) project. To resolve it I had to select config.xml in the Navigator pane and tick the required target in the "Target Membership" box on the right-hand side.